# Message box does not work in release mode

Tags: c#

I have the following code in a C# windows form application.

```
if (myGrid.Rows.Count != 0)
{
     // do something
}
else
{
     MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

The message box shows up in Debug mode but not in release mode. Any idea why?

I am having similar issues with other code as well

For instance

```
 if (!myParameter)
     this.mycheckBox.Enabled = false;
 else
     this.mycheckBox.Enabled = true;
```

The above code works in debug mode not in release. Not sure why.

Thanks

Comment: put a break point and see whether it's hitting the conditional. BPs work in release mode, just FYI.

Comment: It is not hitting the conditional. I dont get this.

Comment: You know that `this.myCheckBox.Enabled = myParameter` is a better coding style don't you?

Comment: Yes I do - It doesnt work with 
    this.myCheckBox.Enabled = myParameter
as well.

Comment: I tried hitting a BP and the message I get is"The breakpoint will currently not be hit. No executable code is associated with this line. Possible causes include: conditional compilation or compiler optimizations. I did not find any settings that I could change to fix this.

Comment: Ok guys I fixed it. Though I had done a clean build earlier several times that could not fix this problem. However I just tried manually deleted the debug/release dirs and rebuilt the solution and it now works. Probably something got corrupt earlier. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4):

In release mode `myGrid.Rows.Count != 0` must be true, try putting another `MessageBox.Show` there.

Answer (score 4):

Probably because your if statement is true in release mode.

Remove the if and keep the `MessageBox.Show("Test");` and that should work just fine

**EDIT**
You can even go a step further by putting a breakpoint at the if statement and seeing what value is being returned.  This would work for both sections of code.

Comment: Not necessarily - my grid can be empty at times. I am having similar issues with other code (edited post). Would you know why? Thanks.

Comment: while its true that my grid can be empty, when you hit that point in the code, the if statement is returning true and hitting the empty block.  In my edit, put a breakpoint (if you have a debugger) and see what value myGrid.Rows.Count is returning.  **EDIT**  Also, is myParameter a bool?  Is it set to true when it hits the if(!myParameter)?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting messageboxes or breakpoints before all your if statements. What is the value of the parameter you are about to test?

If this does not shed any light, make a new, empty winForms project, and put in a messagebox with no conditions. If that works, start adding your old code to it piece by piece and watch to see where it breaks.